# what is the url munging in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

what is the use of the url munging & how ?

Comment: What URL munging in asp.net? What are you referring to? Do you have a link that discusses this?

Comment: Url Mangling? Url Managing? You are talking about somekind of url routing/rewriting or obscuring a url?

Answer (score 1):

No Aristos, user514430 is asking about **URL MUNGING** and not MANGLING.

In Cookieless state, Modifying the Session ID to unidentifiable form and inserting it into the URL of Target Page is called URL Munging. And new created URL is called munged URL.
This is automatically handled by ASP.NET.

Referred from book:
Apress Beginning asp.net 4 in C Sharp 2010 by Matthew MacDonald.

Sophisticated article here:[URL Munging in ASP.NET with Example](http://adityabokade.blogspot.in/2012/03/url-munging-in-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is talk about **URL Mangling that is the 'correction' of the backslashes in the url.**

For example if some type **www.site.com/a/b\c.aspx** if the asp.net is going to correct it and the url be done **www.site.com/a/b/c.aspx**

From what I have see the asp.net did not automatically correct this slash and this left to the programmer to do it if he likes.

refrence:
http://nullprogram.com/blog/2009/06/28/

Test page
http://nullprogram.com/download/slashtest/